# pgAdmin4 version 3.1 how to update to the last version

Tags: pgadmin-4

We use the pgAdmin4 version 3.1 on Red Hat connecting to a server PostgresQL 9.6.
In the log of the server, I notice some errors generated by the pga4dash :

```
ERROR:  column "waiting" does not exist at character 193
```

Indeed, the column waiting has been renamed to wait_event in Postgresql 9.6.

I tried to upgrade the pgadmin4 package by using :

```
yum updgrade pgadmin4
```

The upgrade was realized without problem but it's still running the oldest version 3.1 instead of the new downloaded (after a reload of httpd daemon)

How can I do to use the newest pgadmin4 version downloaded? I search on the documentation of pgadmin and there are no notes about an upgrade of the pgAdmin4

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just recreated the configuration file in the apache2 directory and restarted the httpd daemon.

This ticket can be close.